# SlideToggle na lateral esquerda com icon

Tags: jquery-toggleclass

Estou com o seguinte código:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideleft" class="slide">
    <button type="button" class="btn-event">ICON</button>
    <div class="inner" style="left: -338px;">Efeito lateral de toogle.  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .slide .inner  {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  color: #66cc66;
}

.slide {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:120px;
    width:350px;
    margin:1em 0;
    background-color:#ffc;
    border:1px solid #999;
}

.slide .inner {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:338px;
    height:36px;
    padding:6px;
    background-color:#4c5;
    color:#333;
}

.slide button {margin:.7em 0 0 .7em;}

#slidebottom .inner {display:none;}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideleft button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $lefty.animate({  
        left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0
    });
  });
});
```

Como posso adaptar meu código para gerar o seguinte efeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro fazer isso com CSS `transition` e um `toggleClass`. Assim podes fazer a margem mudar cada vez que adicionares a classe e usando o CSS para fazer a animação.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideleft button').click(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass('aberto').next().toggleClass('aberto');
    });
});
```

e CSS:

```
.slide .aberto{
    margin-left: 200px;
}
.slide * {
    transition: margin-left 1s;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4L6kpfdz/2

Comment: Entendi. Mas o texto tem que voltar a sumir quando ele clicar no botão para voltar ao estado normal....

Comment: @HitchLeonardo claro, erro meu. Escreví `addClass` e devia ser `toggleClass`. Corrigi.

Comment: Ótimo! Muito obrigado. Abraços. ;)